# Schematic for N64 controller to PC adapter confusing

Tags: schematics

I'm working on [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Adapting-a-Nintendo-64-Joystick-to-a-PC/80) currently.

I'm a bit confused as to how this tutorial expects me to connect it to the controller. It just shows the controller plug with the three holes. How exactly do I connect the wire into that? It says the left hole is a ground wire. The bottom wire, is that referring to the middle? Is the wire to the left referring to the left hole?

Sorry for all the questions. Probably the last for now on this.

Comment: No worries about the questions. Electronics is a wonderful world and people on this site enjoy helping others discover the beauty of it.

Comment: Do you own a multimeter? I have no clue about what a N64 controller looks like, but maybe this image will help: http://ezhid.sourceforge.net/n64pad.png

Comment: I actually do have one. I'll look for it. You're just saying I should put the end in the holes and see if it returns anything?

Comment: http://skytroniks.com/images/n64contports.jpg That one looks helpful

Comment: With your multimeter you can find out at the console end which pin is +3.3V and which is ground. According to the image at skytroniks, *at the console*, left terminal is + and right terminal is -.

Comment: That picture looks like its what the controller plugs into, not the plug.

Comment: If you know console side, controller side is easily figured out, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, so they're just saying the wires come out of their console side? Meaning I just stick the wires in for my project?

Comment: You lost me, join the chat again where you were couple of minutes ago.

Comment: VTC as unclear now that the link no longer exists. This is now a perfect example of why I VTC everything as unclear if the question requires visiting a third-party website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret the schematic like you: left (1)is ground, the middle one (2) connects to R1/R3/R4, the right one (3) connects to DB25-9.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the middle one. It looks like they're referring to a bold wire (not sure what that signifies) that goes off to R4. Still though. I have no clue how they actually want me to connect them. The plug looks like [this](http://www.toysnjoys.com/access_n64/m5446.jpg) (right one)

Comment: @MarkLyons you seem to be right, light gray on a white background isn't that readable. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, glad that checks out. Any idea how to actually connect though?

Comment: @MarkLyons i never used a N64, but maybe just stick the wires in? Maybe use wire ferrules to make a connector that is stiff enough. Also since you seem to be new here: If the anwser satisfies you, you can upvote it and/or mark it as best answer.

Comment: @MarkLyons - maybe you can adapt something like a standard 2.54mm header to plug into the joystick connector.